# Is it possible to update an apk on one device and install the updated version in another device?

Tags: android, windows, adb

Scenario: there are multiple devices installed with apk `x`, the apk is asking to update to a new version

I update it on a single device and exported the `base.apk` to windows, then on the others devices I did:

```
hd-adb.exe -s 127.0.0.1:5805 install -r C:\Users\base.apk
```

Now when I try to launch it, the apk doesn't work anymore, it stuck in a white screen.

Inside of the apk folder when I call for `adb shell ls`, I can see these apks:

```
000081a4 00b41380 62853bc0 split_config.x86.apk
000081a4 4ebff13a 62853bd7 split_asset_base.apk
000041ed 00001000 62853bde .
000041ed 00001000 62853bde lib
000081a4 00013199 62853bbd split_config.en.apk
000041f9 00001000 629a2b59 ..
000081a4 0002818f 62853bbc split_config.hdpi.apk
000081a4 016b481f 62853bbc base.apk
000041f9 00001000 62853bde oat
```

`base.apk` is just 22mb while `split_asset_base.apk` is 1.2gb

Is not possible to update it this way or I'm missing something?

Comment: Why have you only exported base.apk on the device which has the updated version installed? Are you aware that apps can use different APKs (or different set of APKs) on different devices?

Comment: @Robert do i need to export all apks and not just base.apk?

Comment: As you never know which APks have been updated I would recommend to always export all of them.

Comment: @Robert also didnt work, i tried to install all at once with `install-multiple -r`